# QGIS changes the value of Decimal (double) Float32 field

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I loaded a layer from a ESRI GDB into QGIS 3.32.1
When I enter a value in a Decimal (double) Float32 field, after saving the edits, the value changes (the change is shown after closing and reopening the attribute table or after pressing the button "reload the table").

For example: I enter `11.6`, after saving the edits, the value is `11.600000381469727`.

Can anyone explain why this happens and how I can prevent QGIS from changing the value?

Here are the field properties:

[image: field properties]

There are no presets in the Attributes Form, which looks like this:
[image: Attributes Form of the Decimal (double) Float32 field]

Comment: That's how floating point works on computers its never exact

Comment: "double" and "Float32" are not the same. 32-bit IEEE floating point is "single" precision. Double precision is 64-bit. It depends on the exact values, but 32-bit doesn't extend past 7-8 significant digits. 64-bit is 15-18 digits. There are some text values which can't be accurately represented at all.

Comment: ok. so this means that this is not an issue caused by using a GDB in QGIS, but the field type in the gdb was set inappropriate?

Comment: @Vince do you know why it is possible that the GDB has a field which is "double" and "Float32" at the same time even though they are not the same?

Comment: What field type would I have to choose to accurately save `11.6`?

Comment: File geodatabase **doesn't** have a type that is both "double" and "Float32".  You'd need to ask the QGIS folks why they represented things like that. `11.6` is `4 * 29 / 10`  -- low primes are notorious for resisting floating-point representation. If you enter "11.6" in a [floating-point representation tool site](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) you might better understand that is a fundamental issue with binary computers, not a GIS-centric problem. Your mistake comes in expecting formatting from an unformatted float.

Comment: Another [floating point representation site](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter). Basically, 11.6 can't be stored exactly as a floating point (single or double precision) value.  What you're seeing in the attribute table is a formatted value and QGIS didn't retain the formatting.